# Active Record Validation Rails 4

Tags: validation, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to validate presence of a zip code upon creation of a book store by checking if the entered zip code corresponds to any zip code in my zip_codes table.

In the book store model, something like:

```
validates_presence_of :zip_code, unless: ........
```

The sql statement to find such zip codes is:

```
select zip_code from book_stores where zip_code not in (select distinct zip_code from zip_codes);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to define your own validation method:

```
validate :zip_code_exists

def zip_code_exists
    errors.add(:zip_code, 'is not valid') unless ZipCode.exists?(zip_code: zip_code)
end
```

That will add an error message on the `zip_code` attribute of your model, unless the `ZipCode` model contains a record who's `zip_code` matches the `zip_code` provided.

Comment: Thank you! Worked great. The only thing I changed is writing :invalid instead of 'is not valid', displays the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a before_save hook instead here.  The way this works, is it calls a function and only saves the record if the function returns true.  So for example:

BookStore.rb:

```
before_save :check_zip_code

def check_zip_code
  connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection

  zip_codes=connection.execute('select "zip_code" from "book_stores" where "zip_code" not in (select distinct "zip_code" from "zip_codes")').to_a

  if self.zip_code&&(zip_codes.include?(self.zip_code)
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

You can also validate the presence of zip_code to simplify the before_save call, since validations happen before the before_save method is called.  You could then assume that self.zip_code is defined.